# thread born and start in java

Tags: java, multithreading

```
class cc extends Thread {
    cc(String s)  {
        super(s);
    }
}

class mainn {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        cc t1 = new cc("first");   
        t1.start();                
    }
}
```

Question: Is the thread born

- at this point --> `cc t1 = new cc("first");`
- or is it born and started at this point --> `t1.start();`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Born" is not a formal term that I've seen before in Java, relating to threads.

The Thread object is **constructed/instantiated/created** when you call `new cc("first")`.

The thread itself is **started** when you call `t1.start()`.  It still exists before then, but is not running, and will not be scheduled by the operating system.

(P.S. Java naming conventions are that class names start with capitals - it is surprisingly confusing to read code that violates this.  `new cc(...)` jumps out at me as somehow *wrong*.)

Comment: The Thread of Execution as a native system resource **will not be created until `start` is called**.

Answer (score 3):

`Thread is born at this point ?--> cc t1 = new cc("first");`

At this point thread is in `New` state which is not `alive`

`t1.start();`

Here your thread is alive but may be in `Running/Runnable` state.

Refer below Java Doc for all `States`.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html

**Example**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread t1=new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("running");
            }
        }
    });
    System.out.println(t1.isAlive());
    t1.start();
    System.out.println(t1.isAlive());
}
```

Which prints :

```
false
true
running
```

Answer (score 1):

If your word "born" creation of new thread object, then it is when you call

> new cc("first")

But a thread process will be forked only you start a thread using

> t1.start()

and it is when  actually ready to run in path of execution from the calling thread.

Answer (score 1):

**-** At this line `cc t1 = new cc("first");` The **Thread Object will come into existence.**

**-** At this line t1.start() the `toe` (**thread of Execution**) will be **created and assigned a** `Runtime Stack.`

Answer (score 0):

Poorly written question but the answer is that it is born at `t1.start();` stage.